# How to modify the default style of SVjour3 such that upper case Greek letters are upright instead of italic?

Tags: greek, capitalization, sv-classes, bm

```
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}
\smartqed
\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{bm,upgreek}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\let\vec\bm
\begin{document}
$\bm{\Psi}$
\end{document}
```

I'm forced to switch to SVjour3 from other document class. But in SVjour3, the capitalized Psi in the above MWE is italic instead of upright as in other document classes. How can I change this default behavior/style with minimum modification?

Comment: if I do `\Psi\bm{\Psi}` neither is upright so it isn't particularly related to `bm` i think

Comment: If you change the documentclass to something else, say, elsarticle, the \Psi in math mode is upright, and it should be.

Comment: You can't say "it should be" (well you just did:-)  `svjour` as a clearly intentional stylistic choice redefines the upper case Greek to be italic. bm is not really involved at all,  `\bm{\Phi}` just makes a bold version of `\Phi` it would be bizarre if `\Phi` was italic and `\bm{\Phi}` were upright.

Comment: The only sensible reason for using a class such as `svjour3` is a submission to a Springer journal. It so happens that Springer likes their uppercase Greek letters to be in italic, unless specifically used with `\mathrm`. In the best case, Your code for changing this behavior will be removed; in the worst case, your submission will be rejected. When in Rome, do as the Romans do.

Answer (score 4):

the class defines the Greek letters to be `\mathalpha` so they follow the math alphabet commands, so you do not need `bm` at all, `\mathrm` and `\mathbf` give upright and bold Phi just as they do P.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{upgreek,bm}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\let\vec\bm
\begin{document}
$\Psi \bm{\Psi} \mathrm{\Psi} \mathbf{\Psi}$
\end{document}
```

The usual advice with journal classes is that you should not alter the stylistic choices either use a different class or if a journal insists on a class they really want to insist on their design,

However if you re-instate the definition of `\Psi` after loading the class then you get the normal upright definition.  the `bm` package isn't really involved in this at all, it just makes the letter bold using whatever style is being used, whether that is italic or upright.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{amsmath}
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\let\savedPsi\Psi
\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}

\usepackage{lineno,hyperref}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{upgreek,bm}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\let\Psi\savedPsi
\let\vec\bm
\begin{document}
$\Psi \bm{\Psi} \mathrm{\Psi} \mathbf{\Psi}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: I already have hundreds of `\bm{\Psi}` and other `\bm{\psi}` in my text. The problem is, `\bm{\psi}` should give me an italic \psi but `\bm{\Psi}` should be upright. This is true in other document class such as elsarticle or RevTeX, but svjour3 looks just incompatible to bm.

Comment: It'll be impractical to change all `\bm{}` surrounding capitalized Greek letters to `\mathbf{}` but keep all other `\bm{}` unchanged. Or is there any trivial way to do that or redefine some commands?

Comment: @noname I don't know why you say it is incompatible with bm, bm just makes it bold so it works perfectly compatibly. Normally `\Psi` gives an upright Psi and `\bm{\Psi}` makes that bold. here the class  redefines `\Psi` to make an italic `\Psi` and `\bm` makes _that_ bold. If it did something else _that_ would be incompatible.  You could put `\let\savedPsi=\Psi` befoe `\documentclass` and `\let\Psi\savedPsi` before `\begin{document}` then `\Psi` will revert to being upright and `\bm` will make that upright Psi bold.

Comment: @noname i added something to my answer

Comment: OK. What I want is nothing but `\bm{\Psi}` or other upper case Greek letters to be bold upright, and `\bm{\psi}` or other lower case Greek letters and all Latin letters to be bold italic. I only need one single command that can automatically switch to bold upright depending on whether it is applied to upper case Greek letters. This is quite simple and this is the default behavior in all other document classes that I used, including ReVTeX and elsarticle. I don't care how svjour3 defines its style, I just want to keep the looking because I am forced to switch to svjour3 from other classes.

Comment: OK. Fortunately there are only 24 Greek letters to be redefine before `\documentclass` and `\begin{document}`. But it will always be better if I don't need to redefine all of them using 24+24 lines but to use only 1 or 2 lines.

Comment: @noname It's wrong to think of `\bm{\Psi}` to be selecting bold upright (even when it selects that) that isn't what it was implemented to do. It selects a bold `Phi` in the same style as `\Phi` keeping the style is the whole point of `\bm`  so `\bm{x}` makes a bold math italic x unlike `\mathbf{x}` `\bm{\Phi}` only makes an upright `\Phi` if `\Phi` is upright.

Comment: OK got it. So what I'm trying to do is to keep the original looking while minimizing the change to my text when switching to svjour3 from other document classes. Is there a simpler way to do that than adding 48 lines?

Comment: @noname you could copy the 24 lines of definition from the base latex files of the slightly different ones in amsmath and stick them in mygreek.sty then just use `\usepackage{mygreek}` in your document.